# How do you switch places with a named mob with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you switch places with a mob in Minecraft?

[image: how do you switch places with a mob or animal]

Comment: I removed the mod related parts from your question, because there are only two possible interpretations of that: Either you're asking for a recommendation for an existing mod, that's off-topic here (on-topic on softwarerecsSE, but unlikely to get an answer) or you're asking how to develop such a mod, which is also off-topic here (on-topic on gamedevSE, but likely to get downvotes, because the real question there would be how teleporting entities works or similar, which is surely documented somewhere already). It's also fairly easy to do with commands, so I'll answer that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by summoning an armor stand (with a unique tag) at yourself, TPing to the mob, TPing the mob to the armor stand, and killing the armor stand.

```
execute at [PLAYER] run summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Tags:["mobPlayerSwapper"]}
execute as [PLAYER] run tp @s [MOB]
execute as @e[tag=mobPlayerSwapper] run tp [MOB] @s
kill @e[tag=mobPlayerSwapper]
```

Comment: Damnit, I'm currently writing the same. :D But I still have another trick ready, because you don't strictly need a dummy entity…

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't just teleport one entity to another and then the other one to the first one, because at that point they're both at the same location. You need some reference to the original location. This can be done in many ways, two of the most straightforward ones are:

The easy way: A dummy entity. You summon an armour stand at entity A, teleport entity A to entity B, teleport entity B to the armour stand and then kill the armour stand again. This is very similar to how values of two variables are usually swapped in programming, by introducing a third one as a temporary placeholder.

Let's say we want to swap the closest player with a mob called "Horst":

```
/execute at @p run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["teleportHelper"],NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Marker:1,Invisible:1}
/tp @p @e[name="Horst",limit=1]
/tp @e[name="Horst"] @e[tag=teleportHelper,limit=1]
/kill @e[tag=teleportHelper]
```

---

The proper way: A function. You can execute a function at the position of entity A (and also `as` it, for convenience), which teleports A to B, but the rest of the function still has the same execution position, you can teleport B to the old position of A. This way you do not need a dummy entity, which causes a tiny bit less lag.

Execute the function like this:

```
/execute as @p at @s run function example:whatever
```

In the "example" namespace of your datapack, have a function called "whatever" with this content:

```
tp @s @e[name="Horst",limit=1]
tp @e[name="Horst"] ~ ~ ~
```